# How do I disable time based trigger in one Google sheet (the old version) while keep it enable in the duplicated new version?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Initially, I thought copying a Google sheet will duplicate the app scripts as well.  It turns out that's not the case.

Background:
I created a version 2 by copying version 1.  I want to make sure that version 1's events will not be triggered in the future, so I deleted the event triggers.  Not until I opened version 2 did I realize that all the event triggers are also removed in version 2.  That's because they share the same app scripts.

Fortunately, it's not hard to set up all these triggers again.  Now my question is, if I want to keep both versions, how do I make sure version 1 (the old version) will not call the app scripts?  BTW, they are time based triggers.  I just want version 2 up and running.  If necessary, I don't mind taking version 1 offline.  I just want to keep it as a backup.

Thanks!

Best regards,
Leo

I deleted event triggers in the old version, then it deleted the event triggers in the duplicated version as well.

Comment: Hi and welcome. This question covers much the same ground as yours: [How do I keep Google Appscript triggers when a copy is made of a sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59453039/1330560). I think you would benefit from reviewing the answers and comparing them to your experience.

Answer (score 0):

"all the event triggers are also removed in version 2. That's because they share the same app scripts." That's not correct.

When a spreadsheet is copied:

- a new Spreadsheet (with a unique ID) is created and
- a new Project (with a unique ID) is created
- **the new Project is bound to the new spreadsheet**

Two things to note

- The Project name will initially be identical to the original Project, but the name can be edited.

AND

- **Installable Triggers are not copied. They must be re-installed.**

The two projects are entirely unrelated - they may share the same name but their IDs are different AND they are bound to different spreadsheets. A function in one project has no bearing on an identically named function in the other project.